# Reading a javascript variable containing a string into another file

Tags: javascript, html

For Example in one file

Test.js

```
var Test = {
String: "Test string"
};
```

I want to read in another js file like this:

Test.String should give me "Test String" as the output.

Any ideas will be good.
Thanks

Modifying question a bit:

I am even not able to read a global variable declared in same file.

var Test = {
String: "Test string"
};

is in the same file.

How I am using it is in another variable.

```
"MyTest":{
"prop":{
        MyVar: "Test.String"
}
}
```

So I am trying to print MyTest.prop.MyVar and expecting to get "Test String" but its giving Test.String as output

Comment: What do you mean by "read another js file"?

Comment: And how is javascript working with this other file? Do you plan to save the file somehow? How?

Comment: hey, the file will be in the computer of the client or in your server?

Comment: Assuming this is on a web page, loading the Test.js file before your other javascript file will allow you to access all of the global variables declared in Test.js.

Comment: please see updated answer, by the way, forgetting about the incorrect usage of the first : , MyTest.prop.MyVar in your case IS equal to Test.String, why should it give 'Test String'?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly: once you have the javascript file loaded, if the variable was declared in global namespace it then becomes available to all other scripts, just so long as you load them in the correct order.
In your case all you have to do is include `<script src="test.js"></script>` then load the second file `<script src="secondfile.js"></script>`

In secondfile.js you can use Test.String as normal.

**UPDATE** after you update: you have declared the variable with a : instead of a =
What you meant is probably

```
var MyTest = {
  prop : {
    MyVar : 'Test.String'
  }
};
```

Now you can use `MyTest.prop.MyVar`

Comment: Thanks. Yes That way it works, now I want to place that global in another js file and read in the same way in the second file. I am not able to do that?

Comment: have you tried calling MyTest.prop.MyVar in the second file? Obviously it will only work if they are both included in the same page.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea also how to pass a string path to a file location through a javascript function. I want to have JS file having single string variable and pass this file location from one javascript file to another via a API

Comment: Please consider accepting the original answer and post the new question separately as it looks to me like your new request needs a lot more detail than you can put in a comment

Answer (score 0):

File1.js:

```
var Test = {
    String: "Test string"
};
```

File2.js:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            $.getScript("File1.js", function(){
                alert(Test.String);
            });
```